# Multithreading in Python , previous and actual data in dictionary are the same

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, python-3.11

I'm implementing a multithreading in Python and I have an issue with the data. Basically (simplifying the code)first thread is collecting data from external source each 0.5s. The code is as follow:

```
dataRef = {}
data_lock = threading.Lock()

def readData():
  global dataRef
  dataRefNew = {}
  while True:
      dataRefsValues = simulate_external_data_source()
      with data_lock:
         dataRef = dataRefsValues
      sleep(0.5)
```

And another thread which checks if previous data and active data are the same or changed

```
def eventCheck():
    global dataRef
    dataRefPrevious = {}
    dataRefActive = {}
    
    while True:
        with data_lock:
            if bool(dataRefPrevious) == True:
                dataRefActive = dataRef
                print('dataRefPrevious', dataRefPrevious,"\n")
                print('dataRefActive', dataRefActive, "\n")
                dataRefPrevious = dataRefActive
            else:
                dataRefPrevious = dataRef
    sleep(1)
```

The problem I got is that during the looping dataRefPrevious is always the same as dataRefActive, why?

Comment: Also `if bool(dataRefPrevious) == True:` is unnecessarily complicated.  `if dataRefPrevious:` will be False if `dataRefPrevious` is an empty container, empty string, or zero value, else True.

Comment: `if bool(dataRefPrevious) == True:` I was playing around (seems to be artifacts after it, :) previously was `if bool(dataRefPrevious):`, but seems `if dataRefPrevious:` is the best option and the simplest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I potentially found a issue but have not a clear explanation why...

I tested a function:

```
def eventCheck():
   global dataRef
   dataRefPrevious = {}
   dataRefActive = {}
   i = 0
   while True:
        i +=1  
        print("\n Iteration: ", i)
        with data_lock:
            dataRefActive = dataRef
            print('dataRefActive  : ', dataRefActive)
            print('dataRefPrevious: ', dataRefPrevious)

        if dataRefPrevious:
            print('dataRefPrevious in if statment: ', dataRefPrevious)
            dataRefPrevious = dataRefActive
        else:
            dataRefPrevious = dataRefActive
        sleep(1)
```

And what I get is:

```
 Iteration:  1
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 0.0}
dataRefPrevious:  {}

 Iteration:  2
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 0.0}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 0.0}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 0.0}

 Iteration:  3
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 1.2505772113800049}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 1.2505772113800049}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 1.2505772113800049}

 Iteration:  4
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 4.265423774719238}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 4.265423774719238}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 4.265423774719238}

 Iteration:  5
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 7.3065643310546875}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 7.3065643310546875}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 7.3065643310546875}
```

**However when I repalce the the following line in the code:**

```
dataRefPrevious = dataRefActive
```

to:

```
dataRefPrevious.update(dataRefActive)
```

I'm getting correct values as follow (previous different than active)

```
Iteration:  1
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 0.0}
dataRefPrevious:  {}

 Iteration:  2
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 0.0}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 0.0}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 0.0}

 Iteration:  3
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 0.20687073469161987}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 0.0}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 0.0}

 Iteration:  4
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 3.2361574172973633}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 0.20687073469161987}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 0.20687073469161987}

 Iteration:  5
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 6.276290416717529}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 3.2361574172973633}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 3.2361574172973633}

 Iteration:  6
dataRefActive  :  {'flaps': 9.321335792541504}
dataRefPrevious:  {'flaps': 6.276290416717529}
dataRefPrevious in if statment:  {'flaps': 6.276290416717529}
```

**I'm thinking that `=` makes a ref of dict dataRefPrevious to dataRefActive dict while `.update()` changes the variable itself.**

Comment: This sounds like the code you posted doesn't accurately reflect what you ran. You seem to have mixed up the concepts of variables and objects, not properly distinguishing between rebinding a variable and mutating an object. (If you haven't read it yet, I recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: It sounds like in your real code, the data reader thread probably modified a single dict object, instead of rebinding the variable to a new dict every time like the code in the question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** What's the very next thing your `eventCheck` function does after it releases the `data_lock`?
**A:** It *immediately* locks it again.

When thread A unlocks and then immediately re-locks a mutex while some other thread B is waiting for it, it's likely that A will be the winner every time, and B will never get a chance. It's not "fair," but it's how mutexes usually are implemented in most operating systems.

I don't know for sure if that's what's happening in your program (it's called, "starvation" by the way,) but if you want the `readData` function to have a chance of going around its loop and collecting some data now and again, then you might try having the other thread release the mutex for a little bit of time now and then.

Maybe just indent that `sleep(1)` call by four spaces? The way it's written, the `sleep(1)` is unreachable code.

Comment: shouldn't thread B be next in line when A releases the lock, if it has been waiting?

Comment: @njzk2, So-called "fair" mutexes are a thing you can find in some programming systems, but that's not how mutexes _normally_ work. Having a mutex be "fair" is only beneficial in a program where the mutex is heavily contested, but a heavily contested mutex is a serious anti-pattern. A program with a heavily contested mutex probably doesn't get much benefit from using threads. An _unfair_ mutex has less overhead than a fair mutex, and being unfair is not a problem in programs where the mutex is in the unlocked state most of the time.

Comment: So in fact due to that thread A is reading from a source and updating dataRef var while the thread B read dataRef and rewrites it to a variable which is in scope of the function then using mutex and `Lock()` the data to be accessible is not even neccessary

Comment: Strange thin... why `dataRefPrevious` is always equal to the `dataRefActive` if I print it out even before the assigment `dataRefActive = dataRef1`

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation, the `sleep(1)` should be inside `while` loop:

```py
import threading
from random import random
from time import sleep

dataRef = {}
data_lock = threading.Lock()


def simulate_external_data_source():
    return {"some_data": random()}


def readData():
    global dataRef
    dataRefNew = {}
    while True:
        dataRefsValues = simulate_external_data_source()
        with data_lock:
            dataRef = dataRefsValues
        sleep(0.5)


def eventCheck():
    global dataRef
    dataRefPrevious = {}
    dataRefActive = {}

    while True:
        with data_lock:
            if dataRefPrevious:
                dataRefActive = dataRef
                print(
                    "dataRefPrevious", dataRefPrevious, "dataRefActive", dataRefActive
                )
                dataRefPrevious = dataRefActive
            else:
                dataRefPrevious = dataRef
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=readData)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=eventCheck)

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

Prints:

```
dataRefPrevious {'some_data': 0.5985874620376193} dataRefActive {'some_data': 0.7163935517084643}
dataRefPrevious {'some_data': 0.7163935517084643} dataRefActive {'some_data': 0.22781975365213092}
dataRefPrevious {'some_data': 0.22781975365213092} dataRefActive {'some_data': 0.6816334934944924}
dataRefPrevious {'some_data': 0.6816334934944924} dataRefActive {'some_data': 0.4299086235625371}
dataRefPrevious {'some_data': 0.4299086235625371} dataRefActive {'some_data': 0.568689886521501}
dataRefPrevious {'some_data': 0.568689886521501} dataRefActive {'some_data': 0.8662567855976215}

...
```

Comment: I indent a `sleep(1)` hovever it desn't help i also move 
`with data_lock:
     dataRefActive = dataRef`
not to lock more  data then needned.

Seems that it is working when simylating random data but when reading sform real source dataRefPrevious is always the same as dataRefActive.